# How can a group manager create new users from within an Organic Group?

Tags: drupal, organic-groups

Is there a way for an Organic Group manager to create new users and automatically assign them to the group? Currently, OG allows the group manager to add users that have already registered to the site, but there is no form that shows something like create user form that is usually only available to the site administrators (as opposed to group managers).

I've also seen the config where the users can subscribe to the group, but it's a different case. What I want is only allow the group manager to create new users and not allow users to subscribe to the group themselves.

I've only been searching for modules and OG configs but couldn't find any relevant search results.

Comment: How about creating a specific rank for the OG managers and allow them to create users?

Comment: It adds complexity when the OG managers also have another Global role. Issues will arise when you want to add permissions to the OG managers and then you need to add those permissions again to the equivalent global role.

Answer (score 0):

hi there you have to use [OG Invite People](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_invite_people)

this module should provide you the invite users in the group from out side of site not already exist users.
when you send an invite to the some one user by email this module should create a user and send an email to the user with one time login link.
invitee should login through this link and update his/her profile information.

and that is done for more info please visit then project page
[OG Invite People](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_invite_people)

thanks hope this will helps you.